# eslint error "Must use destructuring props assignment "

Tags: reactjs, next.js, eslint

Someone know how i fiz that error?
My code works like this, but I get this error, I've tried several ways, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
  13:17  error    Must use destructuring props assignment



export default function Cadastro(props) {
  const Email = props.user.email;

  console.log(Email);

  const email = Email;
```

I got it my props this way:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req }) => {
  const { user } = await getSession({ req });

  return {
    props: {
      user,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: Try this:  `const { email: Email } = props.user;` in addition you can also do `function Cadastro({ user })`

Comment: Or `const { user: { email }} = props;` - Although my personal preference is @MorKadosh's syntax

Answer (score 2):

You have to change from:

```js
export default function Cadastro(props) {
  const Email = props.user.email;
```

To:

```js
export default function Cadastro({ user }) {
  const Email = user.email; 
  // ...
```

Also, take into consideration you will have to do this for any prop which you're expecting. Like:

```
export default function Cadastro({ user, prop1, prop2, ..., propN })
```